# SQLserver Timestamp trying to set a default getting unreadable result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a time stamp field in a table and I've unticked the box in designer for allowing Nulls
I'm unable to enter anything in default value and binding field ( this is greyed out and doesn't allow you type anything )
I'm trying all my sql experiments out in the query designer of sql server express 2008

If I Insert a new record into the table the timestamp field gives a value that looks like:
0x00000000000007D7

As you can see this is totally unreadable:

How can I get round this/ get a readable time stamp in there?

Answer (score 4):

Use `DATETIME` with a default constraint of `GETDATE`

You can do that like this:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    myTimeStamp datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()
)
```

`TIMESTAMP` is a binary field used for row versioning and cannot be edited.

From [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631%28v=sql.80%29.aspx):

> timestamp is a  data type that exposes automatically generated binary numbers, which are guaranteed to be unique within a database.
>   timestamp is used typically as a mechanism for version-stamping table
>   rows. The storage size is 8 bytes.

Comment: Sorry to ask but if the table is already there how do I alter it for this ?

Comment: The easiest way would probably be: `ALTER TABLE myTable DROP COLUMN myTimestamp` then `ALTER TABLE myTable ADD myTimeStamp DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()` full syntax and options here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx